# Mostrar la consola CMD que se esta ejecutando en otra sesión

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2012

Mi problema es el siguiente y de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Se esta ejecutando un microservicio en Windows Server por lo que el CMD de ese microservicio esta minimizado. Cuando entro a ese server con una sesión distinta y con el mismo usuario no logro ver el CMD minimizado, aunque este si esta ejecutándose.

**¿Alguien sabe si existe un comando para mostrar la consola CMD que se esta ejecutando en otra sesión?**

Investigando en internet no encuentro algún comando que me solucione este problema.

Comment: Y no puede arrancar su servicio como un servicio de Windows?

Comment: Hola @Duston lamentablemente no puedo hacer eso.